# proving a matrix is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-groups

Let $A$ be an $nxn $ symmetric matrix.

a) Show that $A^2 $ is symmetric.

b) Show that $2A^2 -3A + I$ is symmetric.

for part a), i have:

$A=A^T$

$A^2 = A\times A$

$A^2 = (A^T)\times(A^T)$

$A^2 = (A\times A)^T$

$A^2 = (A^2)^T$

since $A^2 $is transposable, it is symmetric.

part b) i can prove similar as part a).

Any correction?

Comment: For part (a), it is clearer to write $(A^2)^T = (AA)^T = A^TA^T = AA = A^2$.

Comment: why would you want to write it in that order? I'm proving A^2 not (A^2)^T.
Also, how can i write power function like you did? thanks.

Comment: A matrix $M$ is symmetric if $M^T=M$. So to prove that $A^2$ is symmetric, we show that $(A^2)^T = \cdots A^2$. (But I am not saying what you did was wrong.) As for typing A^T, just put dollar signs on the left and the right to get $A^T$.

Comment: It's a vice versa situation here with the $A^T$. Thanks Lee.

Comment: look at this. Prove: If $A^T * A$=$A$, then $A$ is symmetric and $A=A^2$.
i have,

$A=A^T * A = A*A = A^2$.

Answer (score 1):

In part b) you will need the fact $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ and $(3A)^T=3A^T$and the same idea solves the problem.

Comment: look at this. Prove: If $A^T * A$=$A$, then $A$ is symmetric and $A=A^2$.
i have,

$A=A^T * A = A*A = A^2$.

Comment: @mickey4691 if you have another question, you should make another post